# Is any way to git shallow clone in SourceTree

Tags: git, clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone, shallow-clone

I am now working with a little large repository. My current solution is shallow clone in the Terminal first, and then drag my folder into SourceTree, is there any way to setting in the SourceTree ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly at the moment (August 2017).

See [`SRCTREE-2745`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2745), a feature request from 2014:

```
Support Git shallow clone & Git clone only one branch
```

Comment: Ok Thx. so temporarily just shallow clone first and drag it into SourceTree.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be my next workaround. because I was checking my english grammar. haha